# Displaying cfs:ui images Meteor

Tags: image, meteor

I am using cfs:ui along with all the other cfs packages to upload and display images. Problem is, I can't get the image display helper's image Id right. Here is the code.

```js
Template.upload.events({
  'change #exampleInput': FS.EventHandlers.insertFiles(Images, {
      metadata: function (fileObj) {
        return {
          owner: Meteor.userId(),
          pic: fileObj._id
        };
      },
      after: function (error, fileObj) {
        console.log("Inserted", fileObj._id);
    }
 })
});
```

```html
<template name="profile">
 
       {{#with FS.GetFile "images" metadata.pic}}
          <img src="{{this.url}}">
        {{/with}}
 
</template>
```

How do I display this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally was able to do it.

Being a beginner, I was stuck at uploading images and then showing them for my users for days. Tried almost each method out there, none worked. asked everywhere, none of the answer worked. Finally , a dead simple package from `cosio55:autoform-cloudinary` worked like magic!!! Just take a look at the problems I faced while using these packages:

1. cfs:ui

`{{#with FS.GetFile "images" selectedImageId}}
// image url
{{/with}}`

problem:

with this was I couldn't get the `selectedImageId` .

2. `cfs:gridfs`

problem :

grid fs stores image in a separate collection. My user list uses iron router to show the user list form another collection. Image was getting uploaded into the images collection. But For the love of my life, I couldn't show them correctly. Each user was seeing his own picture rather than the profile owner's picture. happened because of a wrong mongo query but I couldn't get the right query. Tried attaching the photo in the profile.profilePicture, but same problem of wrong image stayed.

And I had to put the upload photo in a separate page and NOT in the autoform.

3. `lepozepo:cloudinary`

Problem: Image uploaded fine. But had problem getting /storing the image url. Couldn't get `public_id`  !!!!! Got lost there.

And I had to put the upload photo in a separate page and NOT in the `autoform`.

4. `autoform-file by yogiben`

same problem as `GridFs`.

**Solution:**

Finally with this `cosio55:autoform-cloudinary` package took me just a minute to figure things out. A *minute vs days* of other big name packages!!!!

`<div> <img src=" {{image}}" alt=""> Image </div>`

just add `{{image}}` in the `img` source and thats it. The image url is stored in the same collection where autoform stores everything.

Cheers Mates.